# Is it possible to start a program with "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" account

Tags: windows-server-2008, runas

This is an extension of the question on SO

If I see a process being run as "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" account, can I start a program with "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" credentials? Something like run as option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to run a command in the System account.

Example:

> Run Regedit interactively in the System account to view the contents of the SAM and SECURITY keys:
>   **psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe**